# Notification bar showing strange shadow Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm working on a project in Android Studio. I created a Navigation Drawer project, using 16 as my minSdkVersion. My Notification bar has a strange shadow [(this is my AppBar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpc0U.png) and I want to have material design's notification bar [(this is Material Design's Appbar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ftpy.png).

Default code is:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" /
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ingsoft.url.gudbox.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" /
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've found similiar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099706/android-toolbar-casting-shadow-on-notification-bar), but they didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"` in the coordinator layout.

Comment: Yes! Now looks normal. Thanks :)